# Set width and height of an accordion

Tags: html, accordion

How can I set the width and height of an accordion so it doesn't fill the whole page? I tried to define the width in a css style but it didn't work for me. Did I miss something here?

```
<style>
    .wrapper { 
            width: 40px;
}
</style>
```

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/L93gA/2/

I have another question: how can I change its position?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the correct usage of JSFiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a beginner. I'll pay more attention next time!

Comment: I wasn't telling you off. Everybody starts somewhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<style>` tag from your CSS code inside `jsFiddle`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L93gA/4/)**

Comment: Great! I'm not familiar yet with this jsfiddle. Thanks ^^